# cannot delete data but successfully connected

Tags: php

i have tried all of the code for delete query, it did say 'successfully connected' but when i put the data, it gives error.

here is my html form

```
<form action="testdel.php" method="post">
            IC:
            <input name="nama" type="text" />
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="delete"/>
            </form>
```

here's my php:

```
<?php
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","jpn") or die("Cannot connect to
                server.".mysqli_error($con));
                $nama=@$_POST["nama"];
                $sql_delete="DELETE FROM register WHERE nama='$nama' ";

                $sql_result=mysqli_query($con,$sql_delete);
                 if ($sql_result)
                     echo "Succesfully deleted";
                     else
                         echo "error due to selected data";

                ?>
```

here is my register structure
[image: register structure]

Comment: check the value what you send and what is in database. echo the query`DELETE FROM register WHERE nama='$nama' `.

Comment: Small doubt, isn't the query executed twice (once while creation of `$sql_result` and during the if condition)?

Comment: change this line to $sql_delete="DELETE FROM register WHERE nama='$nama' ";

-----
$sql_delete="DELETE FROM register WHERE nama='".$nama."' ";

Comment: try using mysqli_error to check your error.

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: @jeff i received no error. and i've used mysqli_error to check my error

Answer (score 0):

## Your solution

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jpn") OR die("MySQL connection error");
if (isset($_POST['nama'])) {
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM register WHERE nama = '" . $nama . "'";
    $delete = mysqli_query($con, $deleteQuery);

    if ($delete) {
        echo "Delete successful";
    } else {
        echo "Delete unsuccessful";
    }
}
?>
```

If you are still receiving an error, perhaps you can go into detail what error message you are receiving.